# ind2sub for nonzero elements of triangular matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I just wanted to simply find the index of (row, col) that is a minimum point of a matrix A. I can use

```
[minval, imin] = min( A(:) )
```

and MATLAB built in function

```
[irow, icol] = ind2sub(imin);
```

But for efficiency reason, where matrix A is trigonal, i wanted to implement the following function

```
function [i1, i2] = myind2ind(ii, N);

k = 1;
for i = 1:N
    for j = i+1:N
        I(k, 1) = i;    I(k, 2) = j;
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
i1 = I(ii, 1);
i2 = I(ii, 2);
```

this function returns 8 and 31 for the following input

```
[irow, icol] = myind2ind(212, 31);  % irow=8, icol = 31
```

How can I implement myind2ind function more efficient way without using the internal "I"?

Comment: `ind2sub` is quite efficient and does not use loops. Are you sure you can get to faster than MATLAB?

Comment: I just wanted to implement it by myself in other language.

Comment: Try to don't use 'i' and 'j' as varibles because they are reserved for imaginary part in complex number.

Comment: type `edit sub2ind` in your console and you can see how Mathworks implemented it. Get inspiration and translate it in your other language. You'll see that 90% of the code is just input checking, the actual calculations for a 2d matrix just take a couple of lines.

Comment: my bad, I meant `edit ind2sub` ... but same reasoning. Plus if you implement one way, you might as well code the reverse operation too.

Comment: @Leos313, using `i` and `j` in a function that only works with dimensions and not any actual data is perfectly fine. There are very few pitfalls or downsides here. The Mathworks does it too in a lot of function and documentation pages. (See for instance the code if you type `edit sub2ind`) I fully agree about not using them in functions and scripts where complex values might occur though.

Comment: @Stewie, you are completly right. But if you are accustomed in using i and j, one day you can find some errors in your Matlab script. If you always use other options you will never have bad surprise because of this topic. There are so many letters, why using the reserved one?

Comment: For the record: I've written the same comment you posted a hundred times, but I've gradually changed my mind. A possible answer: You can do it because everyone does it. Most languages use `i` and `j` as the default iterators (including MATLAB's internal functions). I believe people immediately think about iterators when they see `i` and `j`, while `ii`, `k` or `row` might be less intuitive. My recommendation is therefore: _Never_ use `i` and `j` when working with complex numbers, use `1i` and `1j`.

Answer (score 0):

The `I` matrix can be generated by `nchoosek`.

For example if `N = 5`  we have:

```
N =5
I= nchoosek(1:N,2)
ans =

   1   2
   1   3
   1   4
   1   5
   2   3
   2   4
   2   5
   3   4
   3   5
   4   5
```

so that

```
4 repeated 1 times
3 repeated 2 times
2 repeated 3 times
1 repeated 4 times
```

We can get the number of rows of `I` with the [Gauss formula for triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

```
(N-1) * (N-1+1) /2 =
N * (N -1) / 2 =
10
```

Given `jj = size(I,1) + 1 - ii`  as a row index `I` that begins from the end of `I` and using `N * (N -1) / 2` we can formulate a quadratic equation:

```
N * (N -1) / 2 = jj
(N^2 -N)/2 =jj
```

So

```
N^2 -N - 2*jj = 0
```

Its root is:

```
r = (1+sqrt(8*jj))/2
```

`r` can be rounded and subtracted from `N` to get the first element (row number of triangular matrix) of the desired output.

```
R = N + 1 -floor(r);
```

For the column number we find the index of the first element `idx_first` of the current row `R`:

```
idx_first=(floor(r+1) .* floor(r)) /2;
```

The column number can be found by subtracting current linear index from the linear index of the first element of the current row and adding `R` to it.

Here is the implemented function:

```
function [R , C] = myind2ind(ii, N)
    jj = N * (N - 1) / 2 + 1  - ii;
    r = (1 + sqrt(8 * jj)) / 2;
    R = N  -floor(r);
    idx_first = (floor(r + 1) .* floor(r)) / 2;
    C = idx_first-jj + R + 1;
end
```