# Take a random draw of all possible pairs of indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider a Matlab matrix `B` which lists all possible **unordered pairs** (without repetitions) from `[1 2 ... n]`. For example, if `n=4`,

```
B=[1 2;
   1 3;
   1 4;
   2 3;
   2 4;
   3 4]
```

Note that `B` has size `n(n-1)/2 x 2`

I want to take a random draw of `m` rows from `B` and store them in a matrix `C`. Continuing the example above, I could do that as

```
m=2;
C=B(randi([1 size(B,1)],m,1),:);
```

However, in my actual case, `n=371293`. Hence, I cannot create `B` and, then, run the code above to obtain `C`. This is because storing `B` would require a huge amount of memory.

Could you advise on how I could proceed to create `C`, without having to first store `B`? Comments on a different question suggest to

1. Draw at random `m` integers between `1` and `n(n-1)/2`.

   `I=randi([1 n*(n-1)/2],m,1);`
2. Use `ind2sub` to obtain `C`.

Here, I'm struggling to implement the second step.

---

Thanks to the comments below, I wrote this

```
n=4;
m=10;
coord=NaN(m,2);
R= randi([1 n^2],m,1);
for i=1:m
    [cr, cc]=ind2sub([n,n],R(i));
    if cr>cc
       coord(i,1)=cc;
       coord(i,2)=cr;
    elseif cr<cc
       coord(i,1)=cr;
       coord(i,2)=cc;
    end
end
coord(any(isnan(coord),2),:) = []; %delete NaN rows from coord
```

I guess there are more efficient ways to implement the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I have added to my question an attempt.

Comment: Thanks. The last line is to get rid of NaN rows from `coord`.

Comment: Is `m` much smaller than `n(n-1)/2`? If so, rejection sampling could be a suitable method. Also, when you say "a random draw of `m` rows" you want each draw to have the same probability, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function named `myind2ind` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235974/6579744) post to take random rows of all possible unordered pairs without generating all of them.

```
function [R , C] = myind2ind(ii, N)
    jj = N * (N - 1) / 2 + 1  - ii;
    r = (1 + sqrt(8 * jj)) / 2;
    R = N  -floor(r);
    idx_first = (floor(r + 1) .* floor(r)) / 2;
    C = idx_first-jj + R + 1;
end

I=randi([1 n*(n-1)/2],m,1);
[C1 C2] = myind2ind (I, n);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the odds, for `i=1:n-1`, the number of combinations where the first value is equal to `i` is `(n-i)` and the total number of cominations is `n*(n-1)/2`. You can use this law to generate the first column of `C`. The values of the second column of `C` can then be generated randomly as integers uniformly distributed in the range `[i+1, n]`. Here is a code that performs the desired tasks:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

% Parameters
n = 371293; m = 10;

% Generation of C
R = rand(m,1);
C = zeros(m,2);
s = 0;
t = n*(n-1)/2;
for i=1:n-1
    if (i<n-1)
        ind_i = R>=s/t & R<(s+n-i)/t;
    else % To avoid rounding errors for n>>1, we impose (s+n-i)=t at the last iteration (R<(s+n-i)/t=1 always true)
        ind_i = R>=s/t;
    end
    C(ind_i,1) = i;
    C(ind_i,2) = randi([i+1,n],sum(ind_i),1);
    s = s+n-i;
end

% Display
C
```

Output:

```
C =
       84333      266452
       46609      223000
      176395      328914
       84865       94391
      104444      227034
      221905      302546
      227497      335959
      188486      344305
      164789      266497
      153603      354932
```

Good luck!